# How can I create a view without a model in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

I just need a basic page to show some static information in a `<p>` tag. How can I create a form that has no model?

Comment: if you want to display it in website then its possible....

Comment: @SorrySemicolon Does it mean it's *not* possible on the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this is with simple Odoo MVC. Just create a controller that will render a view; define the view to be rendered and register the view. I found a tutorial here: https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/creating-webpages-controllers-odoo10/

Note that (as of the time of this posting) the tutorial has an error in the view's XML -- line 16 and 17 need to be swapped so that the XML is nested properly.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create a QWeb Report wich are standard web pages.

openacademy/views/report.xml

```
<template id='template_id'>
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
                    <h2>Report title</h2>
                    <p> report text </p>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Place the report in the manifest file
openacademy/**manifest**.py

```
# always loaded
    'data': [
    'views/openacademy.xml',
    'views/report.xml',
],
```

[Documentation on QWeb Report](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/reports.html)

Comment: Is that for Odoo 10?  The question is tagged `odoo-10`

Comment: I get an error when adding the report to the 'data' element. Since this is qweb, doesn't it belong in the qweb element?  The documentation does not say. Also, it does not say how to establish a menu for the report. One of the many terrible Odoo books I have simply says "Use this view in a report tag" and gives me the report tag ... but does not tell me what file that report tag is supposed to be in.